# Proofs with absolutely summable sequences

Tags: metric-spaces, cesaro-summable

(I'm sorry if someone has already asked a similar question, I couldn't find anything from my search).

[The question is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayPdJ.jpg)

> Let $l^1$ denote the space of all absolutely summable sequences, i.e., the space of all sequences ${a_n}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|$ converges. Define,
>
> $d_1({a_n},{b_n})$ = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n - b_n|$ for all ${a_n},{b_n}\in l^1$ 
>
> Show that:
>
>  (1) $d_1$ is a metric in $l^1$.
>
>  (2) Let 0 be the zero sequence (0,0,...). Describe the close unit ball $B$ with center 0 in ($l^1, d_1$).
>
>  (3) Show that $B$ is not sequentially compact.

I'm not exactly sure what the question is asking...I know a metric space is a space in which distances between all members are well-defined, but I'm not sure what it would mean for $d_1$ to be a metric in $l^1$...

Comment: Please type your problem in your post.

Comment: @TimThayer Done. Sorry, still getting familiar with the code.

Comment: Your characterization of a "metric space" is incomplete. Do you know the definition of a "metric" on a set?

Comment: @LeeMosher do you mean:
1) $d(x,y) > 0$
2) $d(x,y) = 0$ implies $x=y$, etc.?

Comment: Yes, particularly since those things (and the etc.) are what you have to prove.